# mysql stored function return total

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

I have a mysql table of employees with columns `surname` and `workhours` for each employee . I am trying to create a stored function that takes a letter as input and returns the sum of workhours of all employees whose surname starts from the input letter .This is basically an easy task but I am a complete beginner in sql and I need your help .

What I tried :

```
CREATE FUNCTION sumOfTotalSickHours(letter CHAR(1))
RETURNS DOUBLE DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
     DECLARE total DOUBLE DEFAULT 0
     SELECT SUM(sickleavehours) INTO total
        FROM employee where lastName LIKE '@letter%'
     RETURN total

END
```

With my above code I get a syntax error since I do not know how to write the query correctly .

Answer (score 2):

First of all, each statement needs to end with a semicolon (`;`).

Be sure you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html to understand how to use DELIMITER when defining stored programs.

Also to reference an input variable, don't put inside quotes.

And don't use `@letter` because variables with the `@` sigil are not the same variable as without the sigil.

So for example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION sumOfTotalSickHours(letter CHAR(1))
RETURNS DOUBLE DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
     DECLARE total DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;
     SELECT SUM(sickleavehours) INTO total
        FROM employee where lastName LIKE CONCAT(letter, '%');
     RETURN total;

END
```